# Where are my iOS Provisioning Profile & Development Certificates created by Expo EAS?

Tags: ios, expo, provisioning-profile, eas

Ran the local expo/eas iOS build process and chose the option to let Expo create a new Distribution Certificate and a new Provisioning Profile:

```
eas build --platform ios --local
```

Now that the certificate and profiles have been created, where can I find them? Are these .p12 files?

Looked into the `Keychain Access` app on the Macbook but dont seem to find them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you signed into your apple developer account. The cert was created there, not locally. You should be able to find it here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list and your provisioning profile here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list.

The eas --local flag specifies where the build occurs but doesn't actually get your credentials locally unless you set up local credentials as described here https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/local-credentials/#setting-a-credentials-source

Comment: What kind of certificate and profile should i create in case i want to build via eas locally? There are a lot of options to choose from